# Symfony nested resource routing not passing ids

Tags: php, symfony

Here's the gist of my problem. I'm creating an API in Symfony2 and I cannot seem to get nested routes to work.

**This Works**

```
api_v1_role_show:
    pattern:        /api/v1/roles/{roleId}
    defaults:       { _controller: rest_v1_roles_controller:showAction }
    methods:        [GET]
```

I can prove that it works by doing something like this

```
function showAction()
{
  var_dump(func_get_args()); // array(1)
}
```

**This Does Not Work**

```
api_v1_permission_post:
    pattern:        /api/v1/roles/{roleId}/permissions
    defaults:       { _controller: rest_v1_role_permissions_controller:createAction }
    methods:        [POST]
```

I end up getting something like this:

```
function createAction()
{
  //This should be array(1)
  var_dump(func_get_args()); // array()
}
```

What am I missing? I've tried looking online for over an hour now and I can't seem to find anything on the subject. I have to wonder if it's a post action security thing.

**REST Class Structuring**

We have a lot of rest end-points in our application. We created a rest class that allows us to quickly add new end-points called the `RestBaseController` and it looks something like this:

```
class RestBaseController {

  protected $urlParams;

  public function showAction()
  {
     $this->urlParams = func_get_args();
     //Shows the resource based on ID now stored in $this->urlParams;
  }

  public function createAction()
  {
    $this->urlParams = func_get_args();

    $this->adjustParameters();
    //creates the resource from JSON body, essentially
  }

  protected function adjustParameters()
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then comes the class that I'm having a problem with:

```
class RolePermissionsController extends RestBaseController
{
  protected function adjustParameters()
  {
    $role = $this->em()->getRepository('AppBundle:Role')
      ->find($this->urlParams[0]); //This will give me an error saying offset 0 does not exist.
    $this->roleId = $role->getRoleId();
  }
}
```

**My Question:**
How would I get a nested URL to work in Symfony?

Comment: dont you have to omit the `Action` part in routedefinition? e.g `rest_v1_role_permission_controller:create`

Comment: I don't think it matters what I call the method that it's calling. I changed it to see if that might have something to do with it and it came back with the same result.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly Does Not Work? Do you receive some error?

Comment: I get a self impossed 422 error when I can not create the resource in my API. But the problem I'm having is that the `roleId` is not getting passed to the `createAction`

Comment: Why are you using `func_get_args()` and not passing the route parameter through the function like `public function createAction($roleId)`?

Comment: I did try `createAction($roleId)` and it did not work. I'm using `func_get_args()` because of controller subclassing. It should return the same results, though.

Comment: Try check is parameter available in $request->attributes->all() (dump this array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found two ways to fix this issue. Dmitry pointed out that symfony uses Reflection and "named parameters" to break down the routes into passable arguments that are similar to `function(Request $request, [ ...$uriExtractedName1, $uriExtractedName2])` which means that I would have been able to something like this in

**PHP 5.6+**

*RestBaseController.php*

```
public function createAction(Request $request, ...$args)
{
  $this->request = $request;
  $this->urlParams = $args;
  //...
}
```

But I'm currently working on a project in an earlier version so I had to something a little more simplistic.

**PHP 5.4**

*routing.yml*

```
api_v1_permission_post:
    pattern:        /api/v1/roles/{parentId}/permissions
    defaults:       { _controller: rest_v1_role_permissions_controller:createAction }
    methods:        [POST]
```

*RestBaseController.php*

```
public function createAction($parentId = null)
{
  $this->parentId = $parentId;
  //...
}
```

This solution has worked out quite elegantly. I don't like having to always call the parent id `parentId` but it's a small price to pay for having exceptionally small controller classes. I realized that the other routers always worked because we call the passed id `id`.

Answer (score 1):

if I'm not mistaken, symfony routing usin Reflection and "named parameters".

For example: route: /api/v1/roles/{roleId}/permissions/{otherId}

```
public fucntion action($otherId, $roleId) // position here is not important, important name
```

Also you can:

```
public fucntion action(Request $request, $otherId, $roleId)
```

and first argument will be $request.

So man, change your architecture until it's not too late

Comment: Haha, unfortunately it is too late; for a lot of reasons. We're planning on extracting the API to it's own service in the near future, so that's nice.

Comment: So I did figure out a way around this, thanks to your Reflection and named parameters comment.